# FullCalendar Not Displaying TIMES

Tags: fullcalendar

I have rendered full calendar with agendaWeek and agendaDay options on a web page. The agenda views do not display time increments on the Y-axis (left pane of the fullcalendar view).

Why would this be?

I have not included any events on the calendar yet. I just wanted to have a blank calendar to start with, but the agenda views have empty slots for each time increment like "10pm, 11pm, 12pm etc" but the time slots are empty white space.

The top left corner of the agenda view does have the label "all day" for all day events.

All day default was set to false when rendering the calendar.

Comment: Hi. Can you show some of your code?